# Java simple while loop confusion

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am having trouble with this simple loop for a uni lab. It wont stop looping until I put in a number over a thousand. I can't see where I have gone wrong on such a simple loop.

I have meant to have written a simple method that will loop through adding numbers until the number is greater than 100 and then once it has reached 100 or greater it will output the total.

```
public void adder2(){
    int sum = 0;
    int number = 0;
    while(number < 100){
        sum = sum + number;
        number = getNumber();
    }
    System.out.println("The result is " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Im sure the error is inside getNumber(). Can you please post that function?

Comment: what is getNumber() returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`while (sum < 100 && number < 100) { ...code as above... }`

Comment: you are correct. The reason I was going by the number variable was because the previous example was to add numbers until the user entered the number -99.

Comment: I think that you got downvoted because without more information your response is just a wild guess which, in worst case, might actually hide the real problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: if that's true case (btw I didn't downvote) than @jamcoupe cannot explain well his tasks. "method that will loop through adding numbers until the number is greater than 100" does not mean that the SUM will also have to be < 100.

Comment: @kol Do you have some magical knowledge of getNumber() that the rest of us don't? :D

Comment: @FailedDev Yeah, I got all these magical feelings and knowledge :) Anyway, it was dead easy: he didn't check whether the `sum` variable reached 100. I always check the simplest possible bug first...

Comment: @kol I didn't downvote, but what if.. getNumber() returns some crazy number? :) you can't know this.

Comment: It was possible, I agree. But if you simply look at the code, you can see that `sum < 100` is missing from the loop condition.

Comment: No you can't. He could be summing all prime numbers less than 100 (as long as getNumber() returns next prime). You could not know what the code actually does given the information. You just made the loop stop. Equally well you could just tell @jamcoupe to set number to 100 in the first iteration or even delete the loop altoghether :)

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, so maybe I misunderstand something. But for me, `loop through adding numbers until the number is greater than 100` means if the number given by getNumber() reaches 100, then the loop must be stopped. And the other part of the sentence: `then once it has reached 100 or greater it will output the total` means the loop also must be stopped when the sum reaches 100. Only the former loop condition was given, the latter was clearly missing.

Comment: once the number reaches 100, not total, at least that's what's written